# how to call a function from one computer to another computer using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, rmi

Every one talking about rmi.js and socket.io ,i'm asking can i call a function from one computer to another computer using javascript like this .

```
Computer1()
{
   call2computer2();
}
Computer2()
{ 
   call2computer3();
}
```

using some socket method or nodejs stuffs?
this is the idea that i want to do please suggest me a way to use rmi in js

Comment: From one computer to another? Or from one file to another?

Comment: i want to call a method in my own computer and the definition of the method is available in another computer how to implement this?\

Comment: how to use that in javascript any libraries or framework available for this?

Comment: I would reccomend [firebase](https://firebase.com) .

Comment: Does it need to be an arbitrary second computer? Do both need to run the JavaScript in a browser? What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I set each computer as nodes so to do this node1 calls a function in node2  then it should execute that function